# Ubuntu server PPTPD with OS X clients Problems

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, ubuntu

I'm trying to get a PPTP server running on a ubuntu server, but I've run into some issues with it. I followed [this guide](http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=132029) on how to set up pptpd on my server, and everything went smooth, but when I try to connect with my mac, it gives me this error:

[VPN Error http://grab.by/31X](http://grab.by/31X)

Here's my configuration:

http://grab.by/31Y

Does anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update:** Here's what the pptpd.log has to say about it:

```
steve@debian:~$ sudo tail /var/log/pptpd.log 
sudo: unable to resolve host debian
Sep  3 21:46:43 debian pptpd[2485]: MGR: Manager process started
Sep  3 21:46:43 debian pptpd[2485]: MGR: Maximum of 11 connections available
Sep  3 21:46:43 debian pptpd[2485]: MGR: Couldn't create host socket
Sep  3 21:46:43 debian pptpd[2485]: createHostSocket: Address already in use
Sep  3 21:46:56 debian pptpd[2486]: CTRL: Client 192.168.1.101 control connection started
Sep  3 21:46:56 debian pptpd[2486]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Sep  3 21:46:56 debian pptpd[2486]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=204d0,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Sep  3 21:46:56 debian pptpd[2486]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
Sep  3 21:46:56 debian pptpd[2486]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[2487]
Sep  3 21:46:56 debian pptpd[2486]: CTRL: Client 192.168.1.101 control connection finished
```

My pptpd options are:

```
asyncmap 0
noauth
crtscts
lock
hide-password
modem
debug
proxyarp
lcp-echo-interval 30
lcp-echo-failure 4
nopix
```

Comment: What's the pptpd log say happened?

Comment: Just added it to the post.

Comment: What about `ppp.log`?

Answer (score -1):

OSX had bad implementation of PPTP - try using a windows client, or run virtualbox and run windows to test the VPN. This cost me two weeks of summer till i found out!

Comment: that is not to say that PPTP wont work, it's just that different terminators, (ubuntu in your case, hardware VPN, windows server VPN service), even using the same radius backend and no change in client configuration, some work, and some don't. (amazing, to be honest)

Comment: i've had good luck with OSX10.6 built-in pptp client hitting pptpd on CentOS with little to no effort, what version of OSX are we talking here?

Comment: I don't think he knows what he's talking about. OSX's PPTP implementation is fine and on par or better than the Windows version.

Comment: I may have made a mistake here, it's the IPSEC implementation that'a bit shoddy, although I do recall there being problems with pptp and OSX early last year (checking help desk cases - yeahup, 5 cases, but fixed with apple update) - anyway, it's a really old question, SO VOTE ME BACK UP. THANKS